# Are these equal? $\int^t_0 \exp(t-s) \int^s_0 \exp(s-\tau) f(\tau)d\tau ds$=$\int^t_0 f(\tau)d\tau \int^t _\tau \exp(t-s) \exp(s-\tau) ds$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I had difficulties while reading the paper.
I did not know why integral is divided and exp function is moved
would you please help me?

$\int^t_0 \exp(t-s) \int^s_0 \exp(s-\tau) f(\tau)d\tau ds$ 
= $\int^t_0 f(\tau)d\tau \int^t _\tau \exp(t-s) \exp(s-\tau) ds$

Comment: It is just changing order of integral.

Comment: Thanks for reply and modified contents, max_zorn, Yimin. I used changing order of integral, but i did not complete it. So, if you know the derived process of that, can i ask to help me?

Comment: thanks! i solved it :)